# Unable to add 'Switch Workspace' to File menu in my RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse, menu, contextmenu, rcp

I am trying to add 'Switch Workspace' option to File menu in my RCP application. I found that I need to use 'ActionBarAdvisor' to achieve this but I am not sure which extension point allows me to configure it.

Also found that 'ActionBarAdvisor' is deprecated. If so, what is the other way to do the same.

Comment: Is this a pure 'e4' RCP (using an Application.e4xmi and no org.eclipse.ui plugins) or is it a 3.x compatability mode RCP? ActionBarAdvisor is not deprecated.

Comment: It is 3.x compatability mode RCP

Comment: Which extension to use to work with ActionBarAdvisor?

Comment: There is no extension point for this. It is one of the advisors you set up from the workbench advisor given to `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench` in your `IApplication`.

Comment: I scanned through all the plugins in my application, I could not find an IApplication. If I have to create one now, how to go about it? Or is there any other way to configure it?

Comment: What do you have configured for Product and Application in your xxx.product file?

Comment: product : my_custom_product and application : org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench

Comment: So the IApplication is the standard Eclipse application which means you can't change the action bar advisor. That application uses the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` action bar advisor which already adds Switch Workspace to the file menu. Is your RCP using activities to suppress some of the menu items?

Comment: Thanks greg-449..my  RCP is using activities to suppress some of the menu items. I removed it and now the 'Switch Workspace' option appears but when I try to launch the app in different workspace, 'Missing System Property' message dialog opens up with a message 'Unable to relaunch the platform because the eclipse.vm property has not been set'.

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you running your RCP from within Eclipse as 'Run > Eclipse Application'? That doesn't set the 'eclipse.vm' environment variable so switch workspace can't run. Running a build of the RCP should work. If you specify the '-vm xxxx' argument in the launch configuration for the Run that should also work.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it works fine on running the build of RCP